# Best practice for computing groups of data in GridGain

Tags: gridgain

I have a large (~100G) cache stored in GridGain where the cache key is an integer ID, and the cache entry is a JSON object.

I need to:

a) traverse the cache in a sorted order (based on JSON field values) -- as if it were a sorted SQL set of rows

b) look for groupings of items -- where a group is defined by running a function like this over the sorted rows:

```
boolean isInSameGroup(jsonFromPreviousRow, jsonFromCurrentRow)
```

c) Modify the data in each distinct group in a group-specific way.  For example, a unique "group id" might be written to every row in the group.

Is there a recommended or best practice way of doing this on GridGain?

Comment: Are you using partitioned cache or replicated? If partitioned, do you need to traverse the whole cache in sorted order, or is it OK to traverse entries stored on each node in sorted order?

Comment: I'm using a partitioned cache, though I can replicate it as well if that's helpful in some way.   Conceptually, I need to traverse all data in sorted order.  However, I could probably tolerate partitions in the total ordering at the cost of possible errors in grouping at the boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert your JSON objects to [Portable Objects](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Portable+Cross+Platform+Objects) which are cacheable unstructured objects in GridGain (see [GridPortableBuilder](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Working+With+Portable+Objects#WorkingWithPortableObjects-CreatingPortableObjects) example), then you will be able to create an ordered index for any of the fields. After that a simple SQL query with `order by` clause in cache will return a sorted collection on each node. You will have to do the total ordering or grouping by yourself though for now (full SQL support, so you don't have to do your own total ordering, is coming in early 2015).

Comment: Thanks for the idea -- I believe Portable Objects are only available in the enterprise edition.  Is there a similar approach for the open source edition?